# Pushing update events without flooding the client. Clean way to do this?

Tags: java, events, event-handling, pushviewcontroller, server-push

I think this is a solved problem but my google-fu wasn't good enough.

I have a table tracking the status of multiple things. Server can push changes to clients at will.

*The problem* is I don't want to push update if the last update is less than 5 seconds ago.

What is the cleanest way of achieving this without making another event manager thread?

My current stab looks like this:

```
pushEvent(){
    Look up the last update time
    if: last update less than 5 sec ago
        then do nothing
    else
        pushToClients
}
```

It works good enough for most part, but obviously the last update could be left unpushed.

What is a good way of doing this?
Some ways I have thought of:

1. Add a 5 second delay to all push (eg Thread.sleep), that way I can
   check if an update has already been scheduled. Not ideal but no one
   would mind.
2. Do the push, then set doNotPush=true. Use a timer to
   set it back to false.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server, you can use `HashMap` which will contain pair `{current event, last sent event}` as values and event's recepients (clients) as keys. Then use scheduled periodic task which will iterate over this map, check if `current event != last sent event` and, if yes, will send current event to client (and put it into`last sent`).

One drawback can be that if sending to client is slow, there can be jams of events in outgoing queues. You can work around this by sending asynchronously (e.g., by offloading events to be sent into separate Executor).